# Confused with react Patterns/Architectures

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, graphql, relay

I'm new to react and while browsing through the net I came across various terms associated with React - Flux, Redux, Relay, Graph QL.

So far I understand these are design patterns for a React app.

I want to embark on a small side project using react and am confused as to which architecture to invest time and effort in learning and implementing .

Could someone please help me out here ? Thanks!

A brief overview of each with the pros and cons would be ideal .

Comment: I suggest ignoring them all while you learn the basics of react

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it can be daunting. The thing is `React` is just a UI component framework (but an *awesome* one) so the rest of the application architecture is up to you. `Flux` and `Redux` are solutions to managing state (not just in React), both are certainly worth learning about. `Relay` and `GraphQL` from Facebook are solutions to fetching data from a server and requires both client-side and server-side implementations to be used.

I agree with Tom's comment: for a small project start with just React (and [complimentary libraries](https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Complementary-Tools) for details like [AJAX](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) and [routing](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)). There are still [basic React patterns](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) to get the hang off. Once you are comfortable with React and your app gets large enough, you will likely start to feel the strain of managing state in your UI, and that will be a good time to seek out something like Flux or Redux.